# Obtener el valor del ID en un ComboBox

Tags: c#

Buen día de su apoyo con este tema, estoy creando un ***Windows Forms*** en el cual tengo un ***ComboBox*** que cargo desde una tabla en ***SQL*** esta tabla solo tiene hasta el momento 2 registros y deseo obtener el ***ID*** del **item** seleccionado para despues almacenarlo en otra tabla, espero me puedan ayudar, ya que no recuerdo como hacerlo.

```
public void CargaComboClientes()
    {
        try
        {
            dtClientes = objConsultas.MuestraClientes();
            if (dtClientes.Rows.Count!=0)
            {
                cmbClientes.DataSource = dtClientes;
                cmbClientes.ValueMember = "Cte_ID";
                cmbClientes.DisplayMember = "Cte_RazonSocial";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }

private void cmbClientes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int cteId = 0;
        if (cmbClientes.SelectedValue!=null)
        {
            cteId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbClientes.SelectedValue);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.ToString();
    }
}
```

Y al hacerlo de esta forma y querer obtener el valor y guardarlo en una variable me muestra esta excepción.

```
No se puede convertir un objeto de tipo 'System.Data.DataRowView' al tipo 'System.IConvertible'.
```

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco más trabajoso, lo sé. LLamadme escéntrico pero no me gusta arrastar los datasets más de lo necesario, y luego las listas te facilitan mucho la vida

```
    private struct Data
    {
        int Cte_ID { get; set; }
        string Cte_RazonSocial { get; set; }
        string Otro_Campo { get;set; }
    }

    public void CargaComboClientes()
    {
        List<Data> datos = new List<Data>();

        foreach (DataRow row in objConsultas.MuestraClientes().Rows)
        {
            datos.add
                (
                    new Data { 
                               Cte_ID = Int32.Parse(row["Cte_ID "])
                             , Cte_RazonSocial = row["Cte_RazonSocial"] 
                             , Otro_Campo = row["Otro_Campo"] 
                             }
                );
        }

        cmbClientes.DataSource = datos;
        cmbClientes.DisplayMember = "Cte_RazonSocial";
    }

    private void cmbClientes_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cmbClientes.SelectedItem!= null)
        {
            Data seleccionado = (Data)cmbClientes.SelectedItem;
            MessageBox.Show("Usted ha seleccionado el ID " + seleccionado.Cte_ID.ToString() + ", con " + seleccionado.Otro_Campo);
        }
    }

    //creo que está correcto
```

Answer (score 0):

En esta parte:

```
    if (cmbClientes.SelectedValue!=null)
    {
        cteId = Convert.ToInt32(cmbClientes.SelectedValue);
    }
```

cambiala por:

```
    if (cmbClientes.SelectedValue!=null)
    {
        var item = cmbClientes.SelectedValue as DataRowView;
        if (item != null)
        {            
            cteId = Int32.Parse(item.Row["Cte_ID"]);
        }
    }
```

O si usas c# versión 7 (Visual Studio 2017):

```
    if (cmbClientes.SelectedValue!=null)
    {
        if (cmbClientes.SelectedValue is DataRowView item)
        {            
            cteId = Int32.Parse(item.Row["Cte_ID"]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Estoy usando la versión 2015 de visual studio la primer opción me funciono solo que cuando cambio de item en vez de mostrarme el ID 2 del item que seleccione me muestra el 1.

Comment: Está raro, igual puedes poner un punto de interrupción para ver que valor está tomando del combobox.

Si quieres usar las nuevas opciones de sintaxis de C# 7 en Visual Studio 2015 puedes instalar el paquete nuget 'Microsoft.Net.Compilers'.

Answer (score 0):

Si cambias en orden de las asignaciones DataSource, valuemember y displaymember debe de funcionar correctamente:

```
public void CargaComboClientes()
    {
        try
        {
            dtClientes = objConsultas.MuestraClientes();
            if (dtClientes.Rows.Count!=0)
            {
                cmbClientes.ValueMember = "Cte_ID";
                cmbClientes.DisplayMember = "Cte_RazonSocial";
                cmbClientes.DataSource = dtClientes;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.ToString();
        }
    }
```

El problema que tu tienes es que cuando ejecutas esta línea en tu codigo cmbClientes.ValueMember = "Cte_ID"; se dispara el evento SelectedIndexChanged pero aun no has asignado el valor a valuemember.